# Numeric Number into Date format in Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, centos7, pbx, freepbx

I am a Novice user in Asterisk,Can anybody tell me that How to read date from customer in asterisk? If anybody knows answer of this Question,please tell fast

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is PBX only. It provide only BASIC operations on data.

You have use Read application and interpret results using dialplan or AGI script.